# Telerik's findNodeByValue works outside the loop but not inside

Tags: javascript, telerik, radtreeview

I have a following code that uses client side access to Telerik's RadTreeNode.

```
 function CallbackUCSPSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
        var tree = $find("<%=Tree.ClientID %>");
```

**here it works and I got some Node :**

```
        var node = tree.findNodeByValue("SECTION_161");
        for (var key in result) {
             console.log(key + " - " + result[key] + "tree "+ tree);
             var foundNode = tree.FindNodeByValue(key);
```

**but here I get: TypeError: tree.FindNodeByValue is not a function**

```
            if (foundNode) {
               // doing things
            }

};
```

It is apparently some syntax issue. Please help me understand how to make this work. Tried to tree both together with 'var' and without.

Comment: var foundNode = tree.FindNodeByValue(key); - here function name starts with capital "F", which is probably a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tree.findNodeByValue("SECTION_161"); and tree.FindNodeByValue(key);
```

Difference is in case :)

Comment: Indeed. Poor reading of f versus F in Visual stuio was a problem